# transpose html table which are taken from another html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to transpose auto generated html table (table.html) and display results in the page (radiator.html) using `frame`.

here is my solution how to transpose my table: https://jsfiddle.net/ascentman/fbvzqmu7/ But the problem is: I don't know how can I apply it for my situation: table.html is created automatically so I can't make there any changes. File radiator.html contains:

```
 <FRAMESET cols="100%">
     <FRAME src="table.html">
 </FRAMESET>
```

By adding js code to the page radiator.html I can't fetch table id from there. Is there is any method how to transpose auto generated table? Maybe I've chosen not the best way to do it. Any solutions?

Comment: you can load `table.html` using ajax. You will get the html in stringified form, which you can then parse and use as you want

Comment: @Mike can it be loaded in the `frame` of radiator.html?

Comment: sorry but I'm not exactly getting what you need to do. Why is their any need for `frameset` and `frame` in the first place?

Comment: @Mike it's just a small part of radiator.html page. There is an array of framesets on a page (3 cols, and some cols also have rows). But it actually doesn't matter. I simply asked how can I process that table.html with ajax to display it in the frame element.

Comment: if you only need to access the contents of table.html after it gets embedded in the frame, you can use `contents` method of `jQuery` [https://api.jquery.com/contents/]